# How can I convert the instantiation of an object to a lambda expression

Tags: c#, lambda

Excuse me, is it possible to convert that code to lambda expression

```
var person = new Person();
person.Age = 17;
person.FirstName = "Todor";
person.SecondName = "Todorov";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's quite useless but yes:

```
Func<Person> person = () =>
{
    return new Person()
    {
        Age = 17,
        FirstName = "Todor",
        SecondName = "Todorov"
    }
};
```

This approach will create some sort of a readonly variable, because every time that you call it you will get a new instance with the hard coded values.

Another approach could be to make a generator function:

```
Func<int, string, string, Person> generatePerson = (int a, string f, string s) =>   
{
    return new Person()
    {
        Age = a,
        FirstName = f,
        SecondName = s
    };
};
```

This is like an external constructor that will generate you different objects which you can parametrize

```
var person = generatePerson(17, "Todor", "Todorov");
```

You can also skip the declaration of the input types:

```
Func<int, string, string, Person> generatePerson = (a, f, s) =>....
```

I did it for clarity reasons above.

Comment: but now, everytime you call person it will init with new values. if you change the `Age` of the person and then call person.Age, it will change back to the init value. Correct me if im wrong, but this seams like it's not exactly the same as op's code

Comment: "verytime you call person it will init with new values" yes that is exactly what it will do, it's like a readonly variable

Answer (score -1):

one of the short thing you can do is

```
new Person(){
Age = 17,
FirstName = "Todor",
SecondName = "Todorov"
};
```